# Aggregation Issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

My query is pivoted twice in order to get the sum of downtime codes in each column and the count of downtime codes in each column.

There are two inner joins to bring in the width and a qty component to perform a calculation for SQM produced and LM produced.

My issue is that my query is getting duplicated records and I feel like I've tried everything to fix it; I need one record for each Date, Machine, LM(produced), SQM(Produced) and each count ( NUM_ ) and sum ( H_ ) for downtime codes.

Data output example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lnQrtP5GO-F_zB7zR2GBvLe8RIa61rA8/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115258646474729421097&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
  SELECT 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.Date, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.Mach AS MACHINE, 
  FORMAT(
    ISNULL(
      ROUND(
        (
          SUM(Table2.qty) / 3.2808399
        ), 
        4
      ), 
      0
    ), 
    'F', 
    'it-IT'
  ) AS LM_CY, 
  FORMAT(
    ROUND(
      SUM(
        (
          (
            ROUND(
              (Table2.qty / 12), 
              4
            ) * (
              CONVERT(FLOAT, Table3.Width)
            )
          ) / 10.7639104
        ) -1
      ), 
      4
    ), 
    'F', 
    'it-IT'
  ) AS SQM_CY, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason1] AS H_Reason1, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason2] AS H_Reason2, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason3] AS H_Reason3, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason4] AS H_Reason4, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason5] AS H_Reason5, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason6] AS H_Reason6, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason7] AS H_Reason7, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason8] AS H_Reason8, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason9] AS H_Reason9, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason10] AS H_Reason10, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason11] AS H_Reason11, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason12] AS H_Reason12, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason13] AS H_Reason13, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason14] AS H_Reason14, 
  NUM_Reason1, 
  NUM_Reason2, 
  NUM_Reason3, 
  NUM_Reason4, 
  NUM_Reason5, 
  NUM_Reason6, 
  NUM_Reason7, 
  NUM_Reason8, 
  NUM_Reason9, 
  NUM_Reason10, 
  NUM_Reason11, 
  NUM_Reason12, 
  NUM_Reason13, 
  NUM_Reason14 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      Date, 
      Mach, 
      DownMinutes, 
      ISNULL(_Code, 'Reason14') AS _Code, 
-- Here downtime codes are being counted
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason1, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason2, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason3, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason4, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason5, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason6, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason7, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason8, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Start-up/Shutdown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason9, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason10, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason11, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason12, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason13, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) AS NUM_Reason14 
    FROM 
      Database1.dbo.Table1
    GROUP BY 
      Date, 
      Mach, 
      DownMinutes, 
      _Code
  ) AS DownTimeTotals PIVOT(
  
--This has to be pivoted for the desired layout

    SUM([DownMinutes]) FOR [_Code] IN(
      [Reason1], [Reason2], 
      [Reason3], [Reason4], 
      [Reason5], [Reason6], 
      [Reason7], [Reason8], 
      [Reason9], [Reason10], 
      [Reason11], [Reason12], 
      [Reason13], [Reason14]
    )
  ) AS Pivot_DownTime_Code 
  INNER JOIN [Server1].[Database1].dbo.Table2 ON Pivot_DownTime_Code.Mach = Table2.coater_desc 
  AND CONVERT(
    VARCHAR, Pivot_DownTime_Code.Date, 
    1
  ) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, Table2.picked_date, 1) 
  INNER JOIN [Server1].[Database1].dbo.Table3 ON Pivot_DownTime_Code.Mach = Table3.Machine 
  AND Table2.[MO Number] = Table3.MO 
  AND CONVERT(
    VARCHAR, Pivot_DownTime_Code.Date, 
    1
  ) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, Table3.Date, 1) 
GROUP BY 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.Date, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.Mach, 
  Table3.Width, 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason1], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason2], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason3], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason4], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason5], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason6], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason7], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason8], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason9], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason10], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason11], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason12], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason13], 
  Pivot_DownTime_Code.[Reason14], 
  NUM_Reason1, 
  NUM_Reason2, 
  NUM_Reason3, 
  NUM_Reason4, 
  NUM_Reason5, 
  NUM_Reason6, 
  NUM_Reason7, 
  NUM_Reason8, 
  NUM_Reason9, 
  NUM_Reason10, 
  NUM_Reason11, 
  NUM_Reason12, 
  NUM_Reason13, 
  NUM_Reason14 
ORDER BY 
  Date;
```

Comment: Please provide a full [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Considering the size of the `GROUP BY` I feel like there's a bigger problem here.

Comment: The possible culprit is “Table3.Width”. You could remove the join on Table3 and check if rows aren’t duplicated…and it is advised to define the length when converting to varchar..`convert(varchar(xyz), date, 1) `

Comment: Add some sample data. and please, do something about the formatting of your function calls, it's not supposed to be 1 line per token

Comment: Thank you all, I added some sample data

Comment: @lptr I tried that but it looks like there are some duplicates. summations of downtime minutes and counts are being added to separate lines

Comment: Your sample data is missing columns (MO Number, MO).

Comment: Instead of the two consecutive pivots, which create the duplicates (the first sum(case)pivot is grouped by DownMinutes, if the same date&mach, has X distinct Reasons after group by DownMinutes then the second pivot will have X duplicates), you could aggregate to get the count() and sum(downminutes) per _Code/reason, unpivot the aggregates (given the compatible datatypes) and then pivot only once for H_ReasonX, NUM_ReasonX columns

Comment: ..`select *
from 
(
select t.Date, t.Mach, u.*
from
(select Date, Mach, case _Code when 'Start-up/Shutdown' /*Product change?*/ then 'Reason9' else isnull(_Code, 'Reason14') end as _Code,
count(*) as num, sum(DownMinutes) as h
from Database1.dbo.Table1
group by Date, Mach, _Code) as t
cross apply (values('NUM_'+_Code, num),('H_'+_Code, h)) as u(col, val)
) as d
pivot
(sum(val) for col in (H_Reason1,H_Reason2,H_Reason3,H_Reason4,H_Reason5, /*..*/H_Reason14,
  NUM_Reason1,NUM_Reason2,NUM_Reason3, NUM_Reason4, NUM_Reason5, /*..*/NUM_Reason14)
) as Pivot_DownTime_Code`

Comment: You could also remove the pivot in your original query and aggregate the minutes in the first group by..`SUM(
        CASE WHEN _Code = 'Reason1' THEN DownMinutes ELSE 0 END
      ) AS H_Reason1, .. Database1.dbo.Table1
    GROUP BY  Date,  Mach,  _Code) AS ..`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the assistance. All look like good explanations.
I ended up:

- inserting the output of the date, machine, LM, SQM into a temp table
- Joined that output on the first pivot of the sum of down minutes
- Joined that temp table on the next pivoted query

For anyone else looking at this question from a search:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
DROP 
  TABLE #TempTable
  GO IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable2') IS NOT NULL 
DROP 
  TABLE #TempTable2
  GO 
SELECT 
  ...INTO #TempTable
FROM 
  ...
  JOIN...(if needed) GO 
SELECT 
  ...
FROM 
  ...(PIVOT Statement) GO 
SELECT 
  #Temptable2.FieldNames...
  SUM (
    CASE WHEN _CODE = 'Reason1' then 1 else 0 end
  ) as Num_REASON1...
FROM 
  TABLE1 
  INNER JOIN #TempTable2 etc
```